# put automatically password of user in pg_restore command line windows

Tags: postgresql, cmd, postgresql-9.5

I want to restore my database postgres using pg_restore in command line and i want to put the password of user directly in the command, I tried this command but doesn't work

```
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -W 123 -d my_db my_backup.backup
```

but the following message is displayed

```
pg_restore: too many arguments on the command line (the first being "-d")
```

Answer (score 21):

Set the password as an environment variable: `set "PGPASSWORD=123"`
You can set other arguments this way as well: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html

`-W` is to force a password prompt, not to supply a password directly, thats why it says there are too many arguments.

Putting it all together:

```
set "PGPASSWORD=123"
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d my_db my_backup.backup
```

Update: Thanks @aschipfl, I initially had incorrect quoting on `set`

Comment: The question didn't ask for it, but using a password file is more secure.

Comment: When using `set PGPASSWORD="123"`, the quotes are part of the variable value; write `set "PGPASSWORD=123"` instead to avoid that...

Comment: If you need to run this from a script you need to export the environment variable. 
                                  `export PGPASSWORD='123'`

Comment: -bash: 123: event not found